# What is an electron reservoir?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons

I always meet the word "reservoir", such as electron reservoir.
I was wondering what exactly the reservoir is. Does it mean a metal that provides electrons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron reservoirs as you say can store electrons, but they can accept and release electrons in a reversible fashion too.

> Electron reservoirs and molecular wires are basic motifs of single-electron devices. Both can accept and release electrons in a reversible fashion, but the former can also store electrons.

From: K. Venkatesan, O. Blacque and H. Berke, "Metallacumulenes as Potential Electron Reservoir Devices", [*Organometallics* 2006, 25, 22, 5190–5200](https://doi.org/10.1021/om060364l).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In silicon based quantum dot device( like a CMOS), is the reservoir the bunch of electrons under source?